# Filter search results on the basis of score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an index in which the 10 documents are indexed and I have performed a match query iin one of the field.The match query hits all the 10 documents and shows all the documents. I have printed the query results on the basis of "from" parameter to filter out the results.
The code is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = ESUtils.getClient("jagaran", 9300);
    ESUtils.clusterHealth(client);

    if (client.admin().indices().prepareExists("football").execute()
            .actionGet().isExists())
        client.admin().indices().prepareDelete("football").execute()
                .actionGet();

    ESUtils.createIndex(client, "football");

    indexParentDoc(client);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("football")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "Manchester"))
            .addSort("_score", SortOrder.ASC).get();

    System.out.println("response5------->" + "\n" + response);
    SearchHits searchHits = response.getHits();

    long totalHits = searchHits.getTotalHits();
    System.out.println("totalhits" + totalHits);

    float fromValue = (float) (0.2 * totalHits);
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(fromValue));
    int newScale = 0;
    bd = bd.setScale(newScale, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
    int from = bd.intValueExact();

    SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch("football")
            .setFrom(from)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "manchester"))
            .addSort("_score", SortOrder.ASC).execute().actionGet();

    System.out.println("Minimized response:" + "\n" + response1);

}
```

In the above code, I have performed the query twice which obviously isn't efficient.
In thehe first query, I have performed to get the total hits and on the basis of the search hits length i have calculated the "from" value to filter the result.
So is there any alternatives so that can I run the above logic using the single query?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use from parameter here? I don't understand.

Comment: Since the "from" parameter acts as an offset and it prints the number of  search results on the basis of the "from" value. I have first printed the search results in ascending order because the "from" parameter value removes the search results from the top which allows me to remove the results having the minimum score depending on "from" value.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand why you want to do all that complicated stuff. May be add an example of what you want to get as a result?

Comment: {
"took" : 37,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 5,
"successful" : 5,
"failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
"total" : 10,
"max_score" : 0.2712221,
"hits" : [ {
"_index" : "football",
"_type" : "club",
"_id" : "paris",
"_score" : 0.2712221,
"_source":{"name":"Manchester United","city":"Paris","country":"France"}
}, {
"_index" : "football",
"_type" : "club",
"_id" : "ktm",
"_score" : 0.13442664,
"_source":{"name":"Manchester Derby","city":"London","country":"UK"}
}

Comment: suppose say the result of search response is my above comment. Now what i want to do is filter the results of match query name:"Manchester United" and print result within certain range based on score value.

Comment: But the score is something really relative. Why not just trying to have the results you want in the first position?

Comment: You want here to remove "Manchester United"? Or just have documents which match "Manchester United"?

Comment: I wanted to match "Manchester United" and the results that I get should have score of certain range. I have tried the min_score concept too but how can i mention the upper limit for score?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the most relevant results? I really don't understand. If you want to match Manchester United, then adapt your mapping, create a subfield raw not analyzed, and use a boolean query with a filter on name.raw with value "Manchester United".